# How to set hierarchy branch in JSCharting

Tags: javascript, data-visualization

I want to make a kinda hierarchical graph with JSCharting to upload in Google Data Studio showing a curriculum matrix network and its pre requisites.

I made a graph like this:

[image]

Each curriculum semester is a column and the classes are under each semester.
But I need to show the pre requisites network between these semesters.

For example:

- EQ101 (in 1st Semester) is a pre requisite to take EQ201 (in 2nd Semester).
- MA111 + MA141 (1st Semester) are pre requisites to take MA211 (in 2nd Semester).

How can I show these relationships when user pass the mouse over the classes?

The idea would be show the relationships like this picture, but only with animation with mouse over.

[image]

The code I made is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Stacked HTML Node Chart | JSCharting</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text-html; charset=utf-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jsc/jscharting.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jsc/modules/types.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
      .department {
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        width: 110px;
        padding: 5px;
        color: #424242;
        font-weight: normal;
      }
      .units {
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        width: 120px;
        height: 200px;
        color: #212121;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 10px;
      }
      .units li {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 4px 0;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
      .units ul {
        padding: 0;
      }
      .units hr {
        border: none;
        background: white;
        width: 40px;
        height: 1px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chartDiv" style="width: 810px; height: 430px; margin: 0px auto;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      /*
Chart with HTML annotations.
Learn how to:

  - Create complex charts.
*/
      // JS
      var config = {
        type: 'organization down',
        defaultPoint: {
          outline_width: 0,
          annotation: {
            asHTML: true,
            label: {
              text: '<div class="department" style="border-bottom:5px solid %color;"><b>%position</b>%name%units</div>',
              align: 'center'
            }
          }
        },
        defaultSeries: {
          mouseTracking_enabled: false,
          line: { width: 1, color: '#e0e0e0' }
        },
        series: [
          {
            points: [
              {
                name: '',
                id: 'dhr',
                attributes: {
                  position: 'Engenharia Química<br>',
                  units: ''
                },
                label_style_fontSize: 14,
                color: 'white'
              },
              {
                name: '',
                id: 'ca',
                parent: 'dhr',
                attributes: {
                  position: '1o Semestre<br>',
                  units: ''
                },
                label_style_fontSize: 12,
                color: '#ba68c8'
              },
              {
                name: '',
                id: 'ca_',
                parent: 'ca',
                attributes: {
                  position: '',
                  units:
                    '<ul><li><b>EQ101</b><br>Introdução a Processos e Indústrias Químicas</li><li><b>F 128</b><br>Física Geral I</li><li><b>F 129</b><br>Física Experimental I</li><li><b>MA111</b><br>Cálculo I</li><li><b>MA141</b><br>Geometria Analítica e Vetores</li><li><b>GQ101</b><br>Química I</li><li><b>GQ102</b><br>Química Experimental I</li></ul>'
                },
                label_style_fontSize: 10,
                color: '#ce93d8',
                annotation_label_text: '<div class="units"><b>%position</b>%name%units</div>'
              },
              {
                name: '',
                id: 'ba',
                parent: 'dhr',
                attributes: {
                  position: '2o Semestre<br>',
                  units: ''
                },
                label_style_fontSize: 12,
                color: '#f06292'
              },
              {
                name: '',
                id: 'ba_',
                parent: 'ba',
                attributes: {
                  position: '',
                  units:
                    "<ul><li><b>EQ201</b><br>Balanços de Massa e Energia</li><li><b>MA211</b><br>Cálculo II</li><li><b>MC102</b><br>Algoritmos e Programação de Computadores</li><li><b>ME414</b><br>Estatística para Experimentalistas</li><li><b>QI242</b><br>Química Inorgânica Teórica</li><li><b>QI244</b><br>Química Inorgânica Experimental</li></ul>"
                },
                label_style_fontSize: 10,
                color: '#f48fb1',
                annotation_label_text: '<div class="units"><b>%position</b>%name%units</div>'
              },
              {
                name: '',
                id: 'rm',
                parent: 'dhr',
                attributes: {
                  position: '3o Semestre<br>',
                  units: ''
                },
                label_style_fontSize: 12,
                color: '#64b5f6'
              },
              {
                name: '',
                id: 'rm_',
                parent: 'rm',
                attributes: {
                  position: '',
                  units:
                    '<ul><li><b>CE304</b><br>Direito</li><li><b>F 328</b><br>Física Geral III</li><li><b>F 329</b><br>Física Experimental III</li><li><b>GT001</b><br>Ciência, Tecnologia e Sociedade</li><li><b>MA311</b><br>Cálculo III</li><li><b>QA313</b><br>Química III (Engenharia Química)</li><li><b>QO323</b><br>Química Orgânica I (Engenharia Química)</li></ul>'
                },
                label_style_fontSize: 10,
                color: '#90caf9',
                annotation_label_text: '<div class="units"><b>%position</b>%name%units</div>'
              },
              {
                name: '',
                id: 't',
                parent: 'dhr',
                attributes: {
                  position: '4o Semestre<br>',
                  units: ''
                },
                label_style_fontSize: 12,
                color: '#4db6ac'
              },
              {
                name: '',
                id: 't_',
                parent: 't',
                attributes: {
                  position: '',
                  units:
                    '<ul><li><b>EM312</b><br>Desenho Técnico</li><li><b>EQ415</b><br>Termodinâmica I</li><li><b>EQ531</b><br>Aplicações dos Materiais em Engenharia Química</li><li><b>F 315</b><br>Mecânica Geral I</li><li><b>MS211</b><br>Cálculo Numérico</li><li><b>Q0422</b><br>Química Orgânica II (Engenharia Química)</li></ul>'
                },
                label_style_fontSize: 10,
                color: '#80cbc4',
                annotation_label_text: '<div class="units"><b>%position</b>%name%units</div>'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      };

      config.series[0].points.forEach(function(point) {
        point.attributes.units = point.attributes.units.replace(/<li>/g, '<li style="background-color: %color;">');
      });

      var chart = JSC.chart('chartDiv', config);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using `jscharting` instead of `chart.js` - those are two separate APIs. [This](https://jscharting.com/javascript-organizational-chart/) is the chart you want to modify?

Comment: yes, but I need to make the relationship between different levels of this chart (course in 2nd semester will have a dependency in 1st semester for example)